# Console2 + putty/Cygwin ssh + xterm-256 integration

Tags: ssh, putty, remote-access, console2

I've successfully switched to Console2 on my Windows box, and I'm quite satisfied with that.
(If you don't know it, try it: it lets you group both cmd.exe and Cygwin sessions in the same, tabbed window).

Now I'd like to integrate my PuTTY sessions too.

I could use plain ssh in Console2, but I *need* 256 colors (xterm-256) for my fancy remote vim setup :-).
Here's the question: **how can I setup a ssh client through Console2 to support 256 colors** ?

I'm currently using Putty Connection Manager for that, and it is almost good enough, even if it doesn't look too stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No can do. Console2 is a UI wrapper around hidden Windows consoles, which are inherently limited to 16 colours as they only have 4 colour bits per character cell.

Have a look at [mintty](https://mintty.github.io) for an xterm-compatible Cygwin terminal with 256-colour support and a native Windows UI. No tabs though, and limited support for native Windows console programs.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [ANSICON](http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/index.html) along with PuTTY, you can have it show up in Windows. Just copy the ansicon files into your console2 directory and then create a new tab using this:

```
C:\Program Files\Console2\ansicon.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" -load PROFILE
```

Source: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx#46f4752f-a42d-4205-be52-4cef95eed79a

Comment: Nice stuff... Although it seems that escape sequences sent the other way round are lost, i.e. browsing command history via arrow keys, or command completion via <Esc><Esc>.

Comment: FYI: when I try to download ANSICON from that link Kaspersky says it has Trojan.Win32.Agent2.fhyp

Comment: @AndreaG By chance you haven't happened to find a solution to those lost escape sequences? I've run into the same problem and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: @dtmland no recent evolution, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Since I need colors only for Vim, my current workaround is to:

- choose a 16-color vim colorscheme (I like solarized dark)
- configure it on remote machine .vimrc
- setup system colors for PuTTY session the same way (for popular color schemes like solarized you can find ready-made config files)
- if you want, you can find color config files for Console2 too

Answer (score 0):

You may try [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) (I'm an author of it).

It supports [xterm-256 color](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Xterm256Colors), but I'm not sure if it will works in ssh. Also, you may run PuTTY in ConEmu tab: "putty -new_console".